# component prop gets reevaluated on change of one Vuex state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have two components with parent-child relations. The parent component can contain any number of child components using a `v-for` loop.

Essentially the child component contains a bootstrap table `b-table` and the parent component is just a wrapper around the child component. Therefore, the parent component can have any number of tables inside it.

The tables have the functionality to check or uncheck rows of the table. I want to keep track of all the selected rows of all the tables inside the parent component. I am using a Vuex store to keep the `id` of all the selected rows from all the tables. Each child component commits to the vuex store after any rows is checked/unchecked. It all works all fine till here. Using the vue devtools I can confirm that the vuex store always has the correct data in it.
(the vuex state property name is `selectedObjects`, it is an array of strings).

Now, I want to display some data on the parent component based of the vuex store value (using `v-show`). I want to show the data only when `selectedObjects` in the store is not an empty array.

I have a getter to get the `selectedObjects` state from the store, and I use this getter in the parent component as a computed property using `mapGetters`.

The problem is that everytime a child component makes any change to the vuex store, the parent component refreshes the `prop` that is passed on to the child components. The `prop` being passed is not dependant on the vuex store at all.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isDataLoaded">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <span v-show="showBulkActions"> Action1 </span>
            <span v-show="showBulkActions"> Action2 </span>
            <span v-show="showBulkActions"> Action3 </span>
            <span v-show="showBulkActions">Action4</span>
            <span> Action5 </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <template v-for="objectId in objectIds">
          <ObjectList
            :key="objectId"
            :objects="getObjectsFor(objectId)"
            :payload="payload"
          ></ObjectList>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    payload: Object,
    isDataLoaded: false
  },
  data() {
    return {
            objectIds: [],
            objects: []
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getSelectedObjects"]),
    showBulkActions() {
            // return true; --> works fine

            //This does not work as expected
      const selectedObjects = this.getSelectedObjects;
      return selectedObjects.length > 0;
    }
    },

  mounted: async function() {
    // init this.objects here
    },

  methods: {
    ...mapGetters(["getObjects"]),
    getObjectsFor(objectId) {
            //this line gets executed everytime the selectedObjects is modified in vuex store.
            //this method is only being called from one place (prop of ObjectList component)
      return this.objects.filter(f => f.objectId === objectId);
        }
  }
};
</script>
```

According to my understanding, the `getObjectsFor` method should not be called when the `selectedObjects` array in vuex store is changed, because it does not depend on it.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent component template depends on `selectedObjects` Vuex store value (through `showBulkActions` computed prop and `getSelectedObjects` getter as computed prop).

Every time `selectedObjects` changes in store, update (and re-render) of parent component is triggered.

And as stated in [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow):

> every time the parent component is updated, **all props in the child component will be refreshed** with the latest value

This means expressions used to populate child components props (call to `getObjectsFor` method in your case) needs to be evaluated. That's why your method is called.

Solution would be to pass all objects to your child components as a prop and do the filtering (done in `getObjectsFor` method) inside your child component as computed prop...

Comment: Not everything in the parent component depends on `selectedObjects`. Especially the prop passed to the `ObjectList` component does not depend on `selectedObjects`. Shouldn't only those parts that depend on `selectedObjects` get updated?

Comment: I'm not the expert on Vue internals but I believe anytime any data "touched" by the template is changed, whole template is re-rendered. Even the parts of template which are completely static and doesn't depend on any component data...
In other words Vue is not able to pick just the part of your template and decide whether it should be re-rendered or not. Its your job to create such boundaries by splitting your template into separate components

Comment: Moreover expressions passed to your child components props are calls to functions defined on `methods` section. As opposed to computed properties which are re-evaluated only when depending data is changed, methods used in the template are evaluated every time template is rendered...

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-txd01. I've created a similar parent child relationship. Parent has a `counter` property that is passed the child components using a method. There's one more property on the parent called `dummyCounter`. The child components are only dependant on the `counter` property of the parent. the parent template has  "touched" both properties. According to what you are saying, when I change the `dummyCounter` property in the parent, the props passes to the child should get updated. But that's not happening.

Comment: Well that's not what I'm saying :)
I'm saying that when `dummyCounter` is changed, `Parent` component template is re-rendered and during that `getProp` function (used to populate child components props) is called. Just add `console.log("getProp called");` into `getProp` method right before return statement....